# Defining queries around a designed database

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database which contains a lot of data and although I was not involved in setting it up it is what I have to work with.

Within this database is somewhat of a lookup table.  However, this table has no link to any other tables.  It essentially takes the following form

```
ID   |  input       |   table_name  |  
-------------------------------------
1    |  Movie       |   movie_tbl   |
2    |  Cartoon     |   cartoon_tbl |
3    |  Animation   |   cartoon_tbl |
4    |  Audio       |   audio_tbl   |
5    |  Picture     |   picture_tbl |
```

The table is a lot larger than the above, but the structure is as above.  So what happens is someone visits my site.  Here, they have an input field.  Say they enter Movie then the above table is called to find the input with Movie.  It then gets what table it needs to look in.  I would imagine that the query would be something like

```
SELECT table_name FROM lookup_table WHERE input LIKE Movie;
```

Now that should return movie_tbl.  I now know that I need to search for Movie within movie_tbl and return all the data for its row.  So movie_tbl might be like this (data would be some type of data and the column names different)

```
ID   |  input       |   col_1  |  col_2  |  col_3  |  
----------------------------------------------------
1    |  Movie       |   data   |  data   |  data   |
2    |  Cartoon     |   data   |  data   |  data   |
3    |  Animation   |   data   |  data   |  data   |
4    |  Audio       |   data   |  data   |  data   |
5    |  Picture     |   data   |  data   |  data   |
```

So now my query will be something like this

```
SELECT * FROM movie_tbl WHERE input LIKE Movie;
```

Now the tables have tens of thousands of lines of data.  My real question is whether the above will be effecient or not?  With the database I was given however, I do not see any other way I could do this (I cant touch the database).  Is there anything I can do to make this more effecient?

Any advice appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Not sure why you are checking for input twice?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you checking for input in the 2nd table? You have already filtered the input from the first table:

`SELECT table_name FROM lookup_table WHERE input LIKE Movie;`

In this case you dont have to make 2 queries. Just the 2nd one should suffice. Or just having Movie data in the 2nd table and separate tables for Cartoon, Animation etc. Because then you wont be accessing the 'WHERE' clause, just:

```
SELECT * FROM movie_tbl;
```

2nd Suggestion: Use = instead of LIKE. No need for pattern matching if you know the exact input string.

Comment: I was doing the second query because once I have the table name, I need to then get the correct row from that table

Comment: It would make sense to me if all the rows were the correct rows in that table. Basically have all Cartoon Inputs in cartoon_tbl, all Movie input rows in movie_tbl.

But I suppose you want the data model to stay intact and not change that. But I say that because then you can do a simple select all from table query without any where condition.

Comment: You can also look into 'Creating Views' if you dont want to change the data model.